# Resolve the promise only if xhr.onloadend has fired before

Tags: javascript

I want to assign `videoLoaded` to `true` right after `myVideo.mp4` is fully loaded. I can do this at the last lines of the code (This is our promise):

```
preload.fetch([
      clipSource
]).then(items => {
    // Using a promise it'll fire when we are sure that video clip has finished loading completely
    videoLoaded = true;
});
```

The first issue is if our URL is not valid we get a `404 response status code`. the 404 itself is a valid response so we will not trigger `xhr.onerror()` because technically it's not an error.

we can track 404 status using:

```
xhr.onloadend = function() {
    if(xhr.status == 404) { // do something }       
}
```

The issue is `onloadend` event fired only after the promise `.then(items => { ....` so if there is not a valid URL we can not prevent the promise to resolve and `videoLoaded` will be assigned to `true` although there is not a valid URL...

I want to resolve the promise and assign `videoLoaded` to `true` only if `xhr.status !== 404` in this situation we can be sure that we have a valid URL.

Here is the code (I have used a setInterval and it works but I think there are cleaner solutions that you can share):

```js
let onLoadPassed = false;
let videoLoaded = false; 
let clipSource = 'https://mysite/myVideo.mp4';

preload();

// Make sure the video clip is fully loaded
function preload(){

(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
  (global.Preload = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

  function preloadOne(url, done) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onprogress = event => {
      if (!event.lengthComputable) return false
      let item = this.getItemByUrl(event.target.responseURL);
      item.completion = parseInt((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
      item.downloaded = event.loaded;
      item.total = event.total;
      this.updateProgressBar(item);
    };
    xhr.onload = event => {
      let type = event.target.response.type;
      let blob = new Blob([event.target.response], { type: type });
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let responseURL = event.target.responseURL;
      let item = this.getItemByUrl(responseURL);
      item.blobUrl = url;
      item.fileName = responseURL.substring(responseURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      item.type = type;
      item.size = blob.size;
      done(item);
    };
    
    xhr.onerror = event => {
        console.log('Error has happend so we restart the video preloading..');
        preload();
    };
    
    xhr.onloadend = function() {
    if(xhr.status == 404){ 
        console.log('404 not found');
        onLoadPassed = false;
        
    } else {
        console.log('File exist');
        onLoadPassed = true;
    }
    
    }
        
    xhr.send();
  }

  function updateProgressBar(item) {
    var sumCompletion = 0;
    var maxCompletion = this.status.length * 100;

    for (var itemStatus of this.status) {
      if (itemStatus.completion) {
        sumCompletion += itemStatus.completion;
      }
    }
    var totalCompletion = parseInt((sumCompletion / maxCompletion) * 100);

    if (!isNaN(totalCompletion)) {
      this.onprogress({
        progress: totalCompletion,
        item: item
      });
    }
  }

  function getItemByUrl(rawUrl) {
      for (var item of this.status) {
          if (item.url == rawUrl) return item
      }
  }

  function fetch(list) {  
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.loaded = list.length;
      for (let item of list) {
        this.status.push({ url: item });
        this.preloadOne(item, item => {
          this.onfetched(item);
          this.loaded--;
          if (this.loaded == 0) {
            this.oncomplete(this.status);
            resolve(this.status);
          }
        });
      }
    })
  }

  function Preload() {
    return {
      status: [],
      loaded: false,
      onprogress: () => {},
      oncomplete: () => {},
      onfetched: () => {},
      fetch,
      updateProgressBar,
      preloadOne,
      getItemByUrl
    }
  }

  return Preload;

})));

    const preload = Preload();

    preload.fetch([
      clipSource

    ]).then(items => {
    // Fired when we are sure that video clip has finished loading completely
  
    let check = setInterval(passedFunc, 50);

    function passedFunc() {
   
    if(onLoadPassed === true){
       videoLoaded = true;
       clearInterval(check);
       console.log('videoLoaded: ' + videoLoaded);
    };

  }
    
    });    
  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the promise and throw an error if the status code is 404, this way the subsequent `.then` statements will be ignored and the result will be captured by the `.catch` statement.

```
preload.fetch([
  clipSource
])
.then(response => {
  if(!response.ok) //better to use response.ok as it checks a range of status codes
    throw Error(response.statusText); 
  return response;
})
.then(items => {
// Using a promise it'll fire when we are sure that video clip has finished loading completely
  videoLoaded = true;
})
.catch(error => {
  //do something
  console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: it enters first and after it the second `then` ??? I see no error... still trying..

Comment: check the status code is `404`. note, however, `404` is not the only failure code. I suggest you check for `response.ok` instead, which returns a Boolean.

Comment: Ok `!response.ok` works... I want to tell you what response logs but it returns `Error: [object Object]`...

Comment: just before `if(!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);`

Comment: can you try to log `response` instead? what do you get?

Comment: I get an array with an object inside consist of `url  blobUrl  fileName type size` of loaded file

Comment: `response.status` should not be `undefined` in that case, you may probably need to check for spelling error

Comment: what about `response.ok`? can you also check `console.log(typeof response)`

Comment: `console.log(response.ok)` returns `undefined` and `console.log(!response.ok)` returns `true` and `console.log(typeof response)` returns object

Comment: it returns the same error if there is a valid URL too... Sorry, it failed...

Comment: `console.log(response.ok)` and `console.log(!response.ok)` are basically the same thing, if one is false the other must be true and vice-versa. Something else may be causing a problem.

Comment: with your permission, I get back the correct answer ... maybe this encourages others to share more answers...

Comment: Yeah, good decision. Sorry for not being of much help. Good luck.